# JPA Entity Lifecycle Events vs database trigger

Tags: jpa

I'm new to JPA. I'm trying to figure out how to use JPA Entity Lifecycle Events as a replacement for database triggers.

It is of course more or less the same, except that in a "before update" database trigger for example (Postgresql), you always have the OLD and NEW records, that contain the values before and after the update.

I was not able to find documentation on that for JPA. Javadoc documentation does not say much on [PreUpdate](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/PreUpdate.html) annotation.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

JPA is a specification only and to study the life cycle I think we need to be specific to

implementations. EJB Entity Beans / Hibernate Entity Beans etc., that have their own

lifecycle models.

Answer (score 0):

Lifecycle events **are** defined in JPA.
They are : PerPersist, PostPersist, PreRemove, PostRemove, PreUpdate, PostUpdate and PostLoad.
You annotate methods in your entity class with the appropriate annotation (one of the above).
The method signature is

```
void someMethodName()
```

It can have any access modifier.
There are a number of limitations on what you can do inside a callback, such as invoking methods on an entity manager.

Specifically on PreUpdate: The PreUpdate is guaranteed to be called at some point before updating the db but says nothing on when.