# When using the @SequenceGenerator/@GeneratedValue in JPA - is a database trigger redundant/unnecessary?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I saw this post ([JPA Entity Lifecycle Events vs database trigger](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8666390/jpa-entity-lifecycle-events-vs-database-trigger)), but it didn't ask quite as explicitly as I am here:

Am I required to have a sequence AND a trigger for when I insert a row with a PK with a value of (null)?

Or will JPA somehow interpret the sequence annotations as a signal to grab .nextVal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you define a sequence on your primary key (@Id annotated field) and you map the sequence using the annotations @GeneratedValue and @SequenceGenerator, you can persist an entity with a null primary key. JPA will automatically call the sequence to get the next value (or get it from its cache).
The primary key declaration should look like.

```
@Id
@Column(name = "TABLE_PK")
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "SEQUENCE_GENERATOR_NAME")
@SequenceGenerator(name = "SEQUENCE_GENERATOR", sequenceName = "SEQUENCE_NAME")
private Integer id;
```

Comment: That's exactly what I wanted to know!  Thank you - I will mark this as the answer in 4 minutes :)